# How i can add border to ListViewItem, ListView in GridView mode

Tags: .net, wpf, listview

I want to have a border around ListViewItem (row in my case). ListView source and columns generated during Runtime. In XAML i have this structure:

```
<ListView Name="listViewRaw">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

During Runtime i bind listview to DataTable, adding necessary columns and bindings:

```
        var view = (listView.View as GridView);
        view.Columns.Clear();   
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            GridViewColumn col = new GridViewColumn();
            col.Header = table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            col.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", i.ToString()));
            view.Columns.Add(col);
        }

        listView.CoerceValue(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty);

        listView.DataContext = table;
        listView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding());
```

So i want to add border around each row, and set border behavior (color etc) with DataTriggers (for example if value in 1st column = "Visible", set border color to black).
Can i put border through DataTemplate in ItemTemplate? I know solution, where you manipulate with CellTemplates, but i don't really like it. I want something like this if this even possible.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="2">
      <ListViewItemRow><!-- Put my row here, but i ll know about table structure only during runtime --></ListViewItemRow>
   </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll have to set your border in the ControlTemplate

```
<Style x:Key="BorderedItem" TargetType="ListViewItem">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="2">
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now you can set this style in your ListView

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource BorderedItem}" />
```

Comment: Thank you! I experimented on DataTemplate in many ways, all i had to do was switch it to ControlTemplate, oh one more thing, with GridView, should use GridViewRowPresenter instead:)

Comment: Thank you both, including @Andrew who saved me probably hours of debugging by reminding us to use GridViewRowPresenter in the GridView case.

Answer (score 27):

Assuming you're using a ListView with a GridView set as the View, then the ListView doesn't show vertical or horizontal lines by default.

If you want to add horitzontal lines then you can change the border on the ListViewItem, e.g:

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn ... />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    ...
```

Comment: "here"? Where is here?